# Is there a \return command to end the current macro?

Tags: errors, package-writing

Is there a `\return` statement in Latex to end the current macro from being processed?

```
\if some condition
  \PackageError{mypackage}{main text}{help text}
  \return
\fi
```

I just think it would be more elegant than putting the main function of the macro within an `\else` statement. Or what is standard practice among package writers?

Comment: Here compilation stops at `\PackageError` so would never reach `\return`. Other than that, no. It does not really make any sense in this type of language.

Comment: Compilation doesn't stop at `\PackageError`. Any code after `\fi` in the same macro will be processed and (presumably) cause other errors to be thrown. Those may be confusing to the end user, hence I'd like to suppress them. I suppose I'll use `\else`.

Comment: That depends on your compilation settings, a normal straight `pdflatex` stops at PackageError

Comment: It is not uncommon for (La)TeX errors to have knock-on effects that cause further errors down the line. So conventional wisdom has it that one should always focus on the very first error message. Users are (or should be) generally aware of this, so a macro that "exits cleanly" might not be that big of a usability improvement and might not be worth the additional hassle if making it exit cleanly makes the implementation more opaque or much less efficient.

Comment: You probably want `ifthen`. It doesn’t call what you want a return statement, but does let you return different things conditionally.

Comment: In LaTeX 2e you can use `\stop` for aborting compilation. I don't take exiting-mechanisms/goto-mechanisms for elegant. You can do s.th. like `\if <some condition>\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{\PackageError{mypackage}{main text}{help text}}{<code in case everything is alright>}`.  ...

Comment: ... Despite expl3-terminology (where the word "function" is used a lot) TeX/LaTeX is not really a procedural/functional/object oriented programming-language. TeX's/LaTeX's programming-paradigm is that of a macro-language based on tokenization and repplacement and expansion/other kinds of processing of tokens. Don't be tempted to try transferring concepts from one programming-paradigm to an other for the sake of getting around internalizing of the other programming-paradigm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A macro is not a function call, it is textual expansion. So if you have

```
\def\abc{111  \return I don't want 222}
```

and used

```
  aaa \abc\ bbb
```

then the first thing that happens is that `\abc` gets expanded into the input buffer  so TeX has seen `aaa`  already but then the input is

```
aaa
   111  \return I don't want 222\ bbb
```

So if you want your `\return` to skip everything from `\return` to the end of the replacement text you are responsible for adding some marker at that point.